# How to align a table within a TD?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have a **table** with 2 `<tr>` and 2 `<td>`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <!-- other content -->
            </table>
        </td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/><td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where the ***** is I need to insert pretty much the same table (which does **not** contain another table).
but when I debug it the table is left aligned.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/abinuv/6)

I want that the **table** in the upper left box is *right aligned* (for knowledge: and *center aligned*).

For example:
The table within is 32px width but the containing `td` is 64px width.

How can I align the **table** to the right?

Comment: He wanted to know about aligning the table, not something within a table

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A `table` is a **block-element**; `text-align` and `align` only works on **inline-elements**.
So for a **block-element** you have to use `margin`:

**CSS:**

```
.centered{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.rightaligned{
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.leftaligned{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<td>
    <table class="leftaligned">
        <!-- Other Content -->
    </table>
    <table class="centered">
        <!-- Other Content -->
    </table>
    <table class="rightaligned">
        <!-- Other Content -->
    </table>
</td>
```

This will work in almost every browser, even **Internet Explorer 7**.

Comment: Yes, `text-align` only works on inline elements, but td `align` attribute works on block elements too.

Comment: Visual Studio says: "Element 'align' is obsolte or nonstandard.

Answer (score 3):

Only the following comes to mind:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right"></td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/><td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or another css approach:

```
table table {
    float: right;
}
```

or inline with float:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="float: right;">.....</table>
        </td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/><td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `float`? Should work everywhere - is this what you are after: http://jsbin.com/evemoy/1/edit?

Comment: @damien : a table is a blcok-element imstead of an inline-element like a text or picture. in fact blockelements only can be placed and aligned with the margin property.

Answer (score 0):

In case the `td` only contains table and no other text or element then below code should also work, only thing it will right align everything in the `td` and won't work in html5:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">*</td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/><td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```